# how can i recover my database of sql server?

Tags: sql-server

we have Sql Server with 27 tb Database ,date store of this Server is San,3 days ago  one of the drive of this server was disconnected and the database has been suspended for 3 days, we don't have any backup from this server,please help us
tnx

Comment: Contact your SAN administrator. He Should have a full backup for the SAN storage using SAN backup tools.

Comment: we do not have any back up , is there anothor solution for that?

Comment: The disconnection of the San Disk, doesn't mean loss of data. It can be mounted again by SAN maintenance Engineer(or the Company responsible for SAN maintenance), especially SAN is RAID and have many protection for data. Can you you edit your question add more details about the configuration of SAN , and add tags: san, raid to get more help from SO community. What's the age of the old backup?